# Running ssh-agent within docker on jenkins doesnt work

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-agent

I am trying to use a container within my jenkins pipeline, however I cant get ssh-agent to work inside it. I am on v1.19 of the plugin, when I run the below code I get

> Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

However if I run the code from outside the image it works perfect, proving that the user has the correct permissions.

```
node('nodeName'){
    cleanWs()    
    ws("short"){
        withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: 'token', url: "https://private.repo.com"]) {
            docker.image("img:1.0.0").inside("-u root:root --network=host") {
                sshagent(credentials: ["bitbucket_token"]) {
                    sh "mkdir ~/.ssh"
                    sh 'ssh-keyscan bitbucket.company.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
                    sh 'git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:PORT/repo.git'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[Pipeline] sshagent
[ssh-agent] Using credentials jenkins (bitbucket_token)
[ssh-agent] Looking for ssh-agent implementation...
[ssh-agent]   Exec ssh-agent (binary ssh-agent on a remote machine)
$ docker exec abcdef123456 ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-qwertyu/agent.15
SSH_AGENT_PID=22
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
Identity added: /home/jenkins/short@tmp/private_key_8675309.key (/home/jenkins/short@tmp/private_key_8675309.key)
[ssh-agent] Started.
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ mkdir /root/.ssh
[Pipeline] sh
+ ssh-keyscan bitbucket.company.com
# bitbucket.company.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
# bitbucket.company.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
# bitbucket.company.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
[Pipeline] sh
+ git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:PORT/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
[Pipeline] }
$ docker exec --env ******** --env ******** abcdef123456 ssh-agent -k
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
unset SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 22 killed;
[ssh-agent] Stopped.
[Pipeline] // sshagent
```

Im completely stumped by this

Comment: The issue indicates that you can't `git clone` because you haven't been properly authenticated. To reproduce, `docker exec -it <your-container> bash` and then try `ssh git@bitbucket.company.com -p PORT -T`.

Comment: @MaratC Im not sure what that accomplishes... I have no problem reproducing the problem.

Comment: Any updates on this @Dom ?

Comment: Never got it working, wound up doing a different work around than using ssh-agent.

```docker.image("img:1.0.0").inside("-u root:root --network=host") {
      withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'id_rsa', variable: 'PRIVATE')]) {
        sh "cp $PRIVATE /root/.ssh/id_rsa"
      }
      withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'id_rsa_pub', variable: 'PUBLIC')]) {
        sh "cp $PUBLIC /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
      }
      sh "git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.company.com:PORT/repo.git"
}```